# How do i map a volume to replace the standard index.html of a nginx container

Tags: docker, nginx, volume, docker-volume

I'm trying to make a simple map of a volume inside an nginx container for study purposes. To make it i created an **index.html** like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TEST</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>SOMETHING</h1>
    <p>Works!!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

At the path in my PC (host):

```
c:/codes/test-docker/html/index.html
```

All i want to do is to have this index.html inside of my nginx container to replace the standard index.html of nginx.

I have tried to run the code:

```
docker run --name ng -p 80:80 -v /c/codes/test-docker/html:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

It didn't returned me any errors, but when access port 80 to see if it really works, i still have the standard nginx standard index.html running.

My actual OS is Windows 10 Home at the version 10.0.19045 and i running all the codes in the git bash terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Linux Docker using WSL2, you use normal Windows file naming on the host side like this

```
docker run --name ng -p 80:80 -v c:\codes\test-docker\html:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

Comment: I'm not used WSL2, but when set up WSL2 and run it, it did worked. Thanks for the help!